# MouseUp is interrupted by DoubleClick

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to mimic some animation when a frame is clicked

```
Private Sub frameGo_MouseDown ...
frameGo.Top = frameGo.Top - 2

Private Sub frameGo_MouseUp ...
frameGo.Top = frameGo.Top + 2
```

But on doubleClik frame is going up continuosly, without going back to the original top value.
How can I prevent this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancel the `DblClick` action in the event

```
Private Sub frameGo_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```